# Create Customize legend for flot chart and get access to items after generation

Tags: jquery, charts, flot, legend, formatter

I have a graph using **$.plot** to created. I'm trying to use option values like 'series.percent' of chart for each data item. the reason behind that is I want to create a customized legend based on graph data.(for exp:show percentage in labelBox). Is it possible to do that?
I 've tried to use Plothover event and then trigger it for all data s . but I cant find any code for triggering that. 
this is the code for hovering:

```
   $(this).bind("plothover", function (event, pos, item) {
                console.log(event + pos + item);
                if (!item) { return; }
                console.log(item.series.data)
                var html = [];
                var percent = parseFloat(item.series.percent).toFixed(2);

                str = item.series.label.replace(/\s/g, '');
                var legendSection = create('<div id=' + str + ' class="col-md-6 cls" style="margin-top: 5px;">' +
                  '<span class="col-md-4 cls" style="padding-left: 1px; padding-right: 1px; display: inline-block; height: 20px; color: white; background-color: ' + item.series.color + '">' + percent + '</span>' +
                  '<div class="col-md-8 cls">' + '<div class="row cls clsR">' +
                  '<span class="col-md-8 cls" style="background-color: white; color: black; font-size: 11px;">' + item.series.label + '</span>' +
                  '<span class="col-md-8 cls" style="background-color: white; color: black; font-size: 11px;">' + item.series.data + '</span>' +
                  '</div></div></div>');
                if ($("#container").find('#' + str + '').length == 0)
                    $("#container").append(legendSection);
            });
```

my questions are :
1)how can I get access to percent and items of chart?
2)how can I know if there's any other **event** that can be bound for plot chart?
3)Or is there any way to customizing legend as I mentioned for labelBox?

thanks for any help

Comment: Is this a pie chart?  Can you create a reproducible jsFiddle or plunker?  Or at the very least show us how you create the plot?

Comment: @Mark thank you for your attention, actually I've already done it like the answer.I ignored the "plothover" event , and use legend instead of that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

well, I found a way to create label with the following function:

```
  function labelGenerate(label, series) {
    var percent = parseFloat(series.percent).toFixed(2);
    var str = label.replace(/\s/g, '');
    var legendSection = create('<div id=' + str + ' class="col-md-6 cls" style="margin-top: 5px;">' +
    '<span class="col-md-4 cls" style="padding-left: 1px; padding-right: 1px; display: inline-block; height: 20px; color: white; background-color: ' + series.color + '">' + percent + '%</span>' +
    '<div class="col-md-8 cls">' + '<div class="row cls clsR">' +
    '<span class="col-md-8 cls" style="background-color: white; color: black; font-size: 11px;">' + series.label + '</span>' +
    '<span class="col-md-8 cls" style="background-color: white; color: black; font-size: 11px;">' + series.data + '</span>' +
    '</div></div></div>');
    if ($("#container").find('#' + str + '').length == 0)
        $("#container").append(legendSection);

    return false;
}
```

The Function return False.the legend ,in option part, will be like this :

```
legend: { show: false, 
          labelFormatter: function (label, series) { labelGenerate(label, series); }
        }
```

and finally this is the createHTML function which I can generate Tags I want:

```
function create(htmlStr) {
            var frag = document.createDocumentFragment(),
                temp = document.createElement('div');
            temp.innerHTML = htmlStr;
            while (temp.firstChild) {
                frag.appendChild(temp.firstChild);
            }
            return frag;
        }
```

, And it works. the legend will be generate in section I want out side the graph part.